# Dropping connection

Tags: ros, joystick, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run joy Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode on Ubuntu 11.4 with ROS electric.  I am using a Cordless Rumble Pad 2.  Everytime I get an [ERROR] [1323140529.624261794]: Client [/teleop] wants topic /joy to have datatype/md5sum [joy/Joy/e3ef016fcdf22397038b36036c66f7c8], but our version has [sensor_msgs/Joy/5a9ea5f83505693b71e785041e67a8bb]. Dropping connection. The joystick is working up to that point.

Any help would be appreciated,
Morpheus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12228/dropping-connection/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error indicates that some node is publishing a `sensor_msgs/Joy` message on `/joy` but your node is expecting a `joy/Joy` message.

It appears tutorial was not updated for Electric. In Electric, the [Joy](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Joy.html) message was migrated to the `sensor_msgs` package and saw the addition of a `Header` field.

The quick fix for your teleop code should be change from `joy::Joy` to `sensor_msgs::Joy`, updating the includes and manifest dependencies appropriately.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1